# Composite keys in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, composite-key

I am maintaining a dictionary that keeps track of the similarities between pairs of objects.
For example, this dictionary could look like this:

```
similarities = {
 p1: {p2: v12, p3:v13, p4:v14},
 p2: {p1: v21, p3:v23, p4:v24},
 p3: {p1: v31, p2:v32, p4:v34},
 p4: {p1: v41, p2:v42, p4:v43}
}
```

Note, that the similarity measurement is symmetric. Therefore, `similarities[p1][p2]` is the same as `similarities[p2][p1]` i.e. `v12 == v21`.

Sometimes, I'll need to eliminate `p2` from `similarities[p1]`; and in doing so, I'll need to remove `p1` and `p2` from all the inner dictionaries in `similarities` as well.
This is tedious and inefficient.

So instead of maintaining a symmetric dictionary, is there a way to maintain a dictionary with a composite key so that I can lookup `similarities[p1,p2]`?

I can't really use a `tuple` since `(p1, p2) != (p2, p1)` and I can't know a priori how to order the tuple.

A `frozenset` is the only other container that I can think of, but that won't cut it since there may still be other keys in `similarities` that contain either `p1` or `p2` as a component. So what container could I use to solve this issue?

Technical info:

- python 2.7
- there will always be exactly 2 elements in this "composite key"

Thank you

Comment: `frozenset` seems like it would solve your problem to me -- Any reason to think that there might be something better?

Comment: Can you use a syntax like `similarities[p1, p2]`?

Comment: @Blender: no that's illegal syntax and can at best be translated into a tuple

Comment: @mgilson: I've actually explained why `frozenset` doesn't work (it was an edit shortly after the initial post)

Comment: And what's wrong with frozenset here?

Comment: @wim: I've explained why `frozenset` won't work. If you could be more specific about why that explanation doesn't work for you, I could explain it further

Comment: Maybe this interests you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2572916/674039

Comment: "since there may still be other keys in similarities that contain either p1 or p2 as a component" - If you mean that you'll have both `frozenset({p1, p2})` and `frozenset({p1, p3})`, I don't see how this is a problem. Otherwise I guess I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: @Dougal: if I remove `p2` from `similarities[p1]`, I must iterate do `similarities.pop(p1)`; and `similarities[p].pop(p2)` and `similarities.pop(p1)` for all `p` in similarities. Does that clarify?

Comment: Does this do what you're trying to do (though of course in linear time, which is far from ideal) for the frozenset case? `similarities = {k: v for k, v in similarities.viewitems() if p2 not in k}`

Comment: @Dougal: Almost: `similarities = {k: v for k, v in similarities.viewitems() if p2 not in k and p1 not in k}`

Comment: (edited) Oh, so you're trying to delete anything that has `p1` _or_ `p2` - missed that. I don't see any non-crazy dict-based options avoiding a linear-time pass on that.

Comment: @Dougal: that leaves `frozenset({p1,p3})` in `similarities` which should also be burninated

Comment: @wim: it comes close, but misses out on the second of my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `frozenset` is the only logical solution. You can find keys that match just one of the values using a comprehension with a set intersection test:

```
def remove_ab(ab, similarities):
    return {k:v for k, v in similarities.items() if not ab & k}

similarities = {frozenset({1, 2}): "v12",
                frozenset({1, 3}): "v13",
                frozenset({2, 3}): "v23",
                frozenset({3, 4}): "v34"}

similarities = remove_ab(frozenset({1, 2}), similarities
print(similarities) # output is {frozenset({3, 4}): 'v34'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably just use a `frozenset`, assuming the objects are hashable.

Alternatively, if they have any well-defined and consistent order on them, you could keep them in a tuple sorted by said order. You could write a little `dict` subclass to do that for you transparently if you wanted.

Or, you could do something like this:

```
class SymmetricDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        a, b = key
        return dict.__getitem__(self, (b, a))
```

and similarly for `__setitem__`.

Comment: I think you'll probably need `dict.__getitem__(self,key)` instead of `self[key]` to avoid an infinite loop

Comment: @mgilson Of course, I meant to write that and then my fingers just typed the wrong thing. :) Fixed.

Comment: To `super` or not to `super` ... That is the question ... ;-).  (Personally, I tend to not use `super`)

Answer (score 0):

If the p_ objects are of a type that supports sorting, could you use a tuple with the two elements always in lo --> hi order?

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem of removing all keys that have that `p_object` as part of the composite