# Symmetrization of scipy sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a simple and efficient way to make a sparse scipy matrix (e.g. lil_matrix, or csr_matrix) symmetric?

When populating a large sparse co-occurrence matrix it would be highly inefficient to fill in [row, col] and [col, row] at the same time. What I'd like to be doing is:

```
for i in data:
    for j in data:
        if cond(i, j):
            lil_sparse_matrix[i, j] = some_value
            # want to avoid this:
            # lil_sparse_matrix[j, i] = some_value
# this is what I'm looking for:
lil_sparse.make_symmetric()
```

This is similar to [stackoverflow's numpy-smart-symmetric-matrix question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572916/numpy-smart-symmetric-matrix), but is particularly for scipy sparse matrices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, it doubles the number of assignment statements, but in the big picture how much of a penalty is that?

`lil` is the most efficient format for indexed assignment, but I've explored in other posts alternatives.  If I recall correctly, direct assignment to `data` and `rows` attributes of a `lil` is faster, though that's mainly of value when filling whole rows at once.

A `dok` is also relatively fast, though I found that assignment to a regular dictionary, followed by an update to the `dok` was faster.  (A `dok` is a dictionary subclass).

But if you go the `coo` route - building lists of `data`, `rows` and `cols` values, creating both `i,j` and `j,i` terms at once is not costly.  It's even better if you can define a bunch of values at once, as opposed to iterating over all `i,j`.

So efficiently creating an symmetric matrix is just a subset of the efficient matrix definition problem.

I'm not aware of any symmetrization functions in the sparse package.  I wonder if any of linear algebra functions have symmetric provisions.  I suspect the most efficient handlers just assume the matrix is upper or lower triangle, without explicit symmetric values.

It's possible that you could create an upper tri matrix, and then copy the values to the lower.  In the dense case the simplest way is to just sum the matrix and its transpose (and possibly subtract the diagonal).  But sparse matrix summation is somewhat in efficient, so that might not be the best.  But I haven't done any tests.

============

The sum of transpose atleast doesn't give me any efficiency warnings:

```
In [383]: M=sparse.lil_matrix((10,10),dtype=int)
In [384]: 
In [384]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     for j in range(i,10):
     ...:         v=np.random.randint(0,10)
     ...:         if v>5:
     ...:             M[i,j]=v
     ...:             
In [385]: M
Out[385]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 22 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [386]: M.A
Out[386]: 
array([[0, 7, 7, 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 7, 8, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

sum of transpose (minus duplicated diagonal):

```
In [389]: M+M.T-sparse.diags(M.diagonal(),dtype=int)
Out[389]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 43 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [390]: _.A
Out[390]: 
array([[0, 7, 7, 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9],
       [7, 0, 7, 8, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0],
       [7, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 6],
       [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 8],
       [7, 0, 9, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 8, 8],
       [0, 9, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 6, 8],
       [9, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 8, 8, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

double assignment approach:

```
In [391]: M=sparse.lil_matrix((10,10),dtype=int)
In [392]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     for j in range(i,10):
     ...:         v=np.random.randint(0,10)
     ...:         if v>5:
     ...:             M[i,j]=v
     ...:             M[j,i]=v
```

I haven't done any timings.

A `coo` approach:

```
In [398]: data,rows,cols=[],[],[]
In [399]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     for j in range(i,10):
     ...:         v=np.random.randint(0,10)
     ...:         if v>5:
     ...:             if i==j:
     ...:                 # prevent diagonal duplication
     ...:                 data.append(v)
     ...:                 rows.append(i)
     ...:                 cols.append(j)
     ...:             else:
     ...:                 data.extend((v,v))
     ...:                 rows.extend((i,j))
     ...:                 cols.extend((j,i))
     ...:                 
In [400]: sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)),shape=(10,10)).A
Out[400]: 
array([[0, 8, 0, 6, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 7, 9],
       [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
       [8, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 0, 9, 0, 8, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 9]])
```

===============

It might a bit faster to make the upper tri coo matrix, and extend to lower with list (or array) concatenation

```
In [401]: data,rows,cols=[],[],[]
In [402]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     for j in range(i,10):
     ...:         v=np.random.randint(0,10)
     ...:         if v>5:
     ...:            data.append(v)
     ...:            rows.append(i)
     ...:            cols.append(j)

In [408]: sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)),shape=(10,10)).A
Out[408]: 
array([[8, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7, 0, 7, 9, 0],
       [0, 7, 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0],
       [0, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 6],
...]])

In [409]: data1=data+data
In [410]: rows1=rows+cols
In [411]: cols1=cols+rows
In [412]: sparse.coo_matrix((data1,(rows1,cols1)),shape=(10,10)).A
```

This duplicates the diagonal, which I need to address in one way or other (duplicate coo indices are summed).  But it gives the idea of how `coo` style inputs can be collected into larger blocks.

Answer (score 8):

Yep, there is definitely a more efficient and simple way. 
hpaulj's answer should work if you are creating a matrix, but if you already have one, you can do:

```
rows, cols = sparse_matrix.nonzero()
sparse_matrix[cols, rows] = sparse_matrix[rows, cols]
```

This should work for all types of scipy's sparse matrices except coo_matrix.

Edit: noted coo_matrix.

Comment: This doesn't work for coo matrix. Works for other types though.

Comment: Got ValueError: shape mismatch in assignment. Any idea why?

Comment: @Null_Space is your matrix square? The code above will only work with matrices with same number of rows and columns. For symmetrizing non-square matrices, you might be able to do, for example, `sparse_matrix[cols[:10], rows] = sparse_matrix[rows, cols[:10]]`, if there are 10 rows but >10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the mmwrite function, which can convert a matrix to a symmetric one. It works also for coo_matrix, and not only for csr:

```
from scipy.io import mmwrite, mmread
import gzip

with gzip.open("mat.gz", "wb") as f_out:
    mmwrite(f_out, mat, symmetry="symmetric")

sym_mat = mmread("mat.gz)
```