# How to load a triangular matrix and make it symetrical

Tags: python, numpy

Given a triangular matrix `m` in python how best to extract from it the value at row `i` column `j`?

```
m = [1,np.nan,np.nan,2,3,np.nan,4,5,6]
m = pd.DataFrame(np.array(x).reshape((3,3)))
```

Which looks like:

```
    0   1   2
0   1.0 NaN NaN
1   2.0 3.0 NaN
2   4.0 5.0 6.0
```

I can get lower elements easily `m[2,0]` returns `4`.

But if I ask for `m[0,2]` i get `nan` when I would like `4` again.

What is the best way of accomplishing this with in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` with transpose:

```
m = m.fillna(m.T)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  4.0
1  2.0  3.0  5.0
2  4.0  5.0  6.0

m.loc[0,2] == m.loc[2,0] == 4
# True
```

---

In case there are column names (like `A`,`B`,`C`):

```
m.where(m.notna(), m.T.values)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  4.0
1  2.0  3.0  5.0
2  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to solve this is to make the matrix symmetrical, I learnt how from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573982/6948859) answer.

There are a couple of steps:

1. Convert nan to 0

```
m0 = np.nan_to_num(m)
```

2. Add the transpose of the matrix to itself

```
m = m0 + m0.T
```

3. Subtract the diagonal

```
m = m - np.diag(m0.diagonal())
```

Then `m[0,2]` and `m[2,0]` will both give you `4`.

```
    0   1   2
0   1.0 2.0 4.0
1   2.0 3.0 5.0
2   4.0 5.0 6.0
```